# is it possible to archive the report of TestNG?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, report, automated-tests, testng

How do I archive the results (report) of the tests in Selenium 2 (Webdriver) so as to be able to return to them? Each performance suite overwrites the previous report, as it can be prevented? I use a simple html report.

Answer (score 1):

//FOR EXAMPLE YOU WANT TO TEST THIS CLASS AND WANT TO CREATE NEW OUTPUT FOLDER FOR EACH EXECUTION

public class TestClass {

```
@Test
public void testME(){
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

}

```
//Then create  new class which will be the start point of your execution, and run it from here


public class MainClass {

    //This code will be your start point of execution
    @Test
    public void testCode(){
        Random randomNo = new Random();
        TestListenerAdapter listener = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();

        //Here you are changing Output directory and archive it for further 
        //use, OUTPUT FOLDER WILL BE ADDED BY APPPENDING RANDOM NUMBER ON IT
        testng.setOutputDirectory("test-output"+randomNo.nextInt());

        //ADD ALL TEST CLASSES WHERE YOUR TESTNG CODE IS PRESENT WITH @Test 
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[]{TestClass.class});
        testng.addListener(listener);
        testng.run();
    }

}
```